# Correctness of proof of generalized Euler's criterion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups, quadratic-residues

My lecture notes on quadratic residues were pretty sloppy, and I was trying to prove some theorems from class. I don't think I'm correct, though. Can anyone tell me if I'm wrong? Specifically, I think Lemma 1 is correct, but the proof for Theorem 1 is incorrect (Theorem 1 is Euler's criterion).

[image]

Comment: Looks right to me.  Is there anything specific you're confused about?

Comment: @D_S I'm pretty sure the proof for Theorem 1 is wrong. It's my hazy recollection of the proof given in class, and frankly I don't understand it. If you do, could you explain me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know from Lemma 1 that $b$ is a $k$th power residue if and only if $r$ is divisible by $d := (k, p-1)$.  So we just have to show that $d$ divides $r$ if and only if $b^{\frac{p-1}{d}} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

In any case, $\frac{p-1}{d}$ is always integer, so nothing to worry about there.  And by definition, $r$ is a number for which $b \equiv g^r \pmod p$.

First suppose $r$ divides $d$.  Then modulo $p$, $$b^{\frac{p-1}{d}} \equiv (g^r)^{\frac{p-1}{d}}$$ Since $r/d$ is an integer, we have $(g^r)^{\frac{p-1}{d}} = (g^{p-1})^{\frac{r}{d}}$.  But $g^{p-1} \equiv 1$ by Fermat's little theorem.  So you can conclude that $b^{\frac{p-1}{d}} \equiv 1$.

Conversely suppose $b^{\frac{p-1}{d}} \equiv 1$. Again use the fact that $b^{\frac{p-1}{d}} \equiv g^{r \cdot \frac{p-1}{d}}$.  You know that if $g^t \equiv 1$, then $p-1$ divides $t$.  So $p-1$ has to divide $r \frac{p-1}{d}$, which means that $$\frac{(r \frac{p-1}{d})}{p-1} = \frac{r}{d}$$ is an integer, i.e. $d$ divides $r$.

Comment: Thanks! I was close, but not quite there :). Can this be rewritten without using Fermat's theorem by using cyclic groups? Specifically, $g^{p-1} \equiv 1$ in a cyclic group.

Comment: Actually, never mind, that doesn't matter, it's a trivial substitution.

Comment: @D_S I think there is a small typo. It should be "First suppose d divides r" instead of r divides d in the answer.