# $ x^2 \equiv a \mbox{ } \mbox{mod} \mbox{ } p$ has solution $x$ $\Leftrightarrow a^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 1\mbox{ } \mbox{mod} \mbox{ } p $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

One of my friends asked me how to solve the following exercise:

Let $p \geq 3$ prime. For every $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ it holds:

$$ x^2 \equiv a \mbox{ } \mbox{mod} \mbox{ } p $$ has a solution $x$ if and only if 
$$a^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 1\mbox{ }  \mbox{mod} \mbox{ } p $$

So we solved " $\Rightarrow$ ". basically using Fermat.
But I have problems with " $\Leftarrow$ ". I explained him how to solve "$\Leftarrow$" , but unfortunately I used
things that he doesn't know. My solution was to notice that $Z_p^{*}$ is cyclic, so there is a generator $g$ and work with that BUT he said they never mentioned cyclic, generator and other terms I used. So my question is do you know an alternative, reasonable solution ?

Comment: Im terribly sorry. I forgot the Exponent $ \frac{p-1}{2} $

Comment: Another solution is to observe that $x\mapsto x^2$ is 2-to-1 among the non-zero residue classes. It follows that $x^2\equiv a$ is solvable for exactly one half of the choices of non-zero $a$. When arguing the other direction you got a necessary condition that can be satisfied by at most $(p-1)/2$ choices of $a$. Do you see why that holds? Putting the pieces together you arrive at the claim.

Comment: To follow the argument I outlined you do need the piece of information that a degree $(p-1)/2$ polynomial modulo a prime can have at most $(p-1)/2$ pairwise non-congruent solutions. That may also be something missing from the friend's background.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313826/242) for one way to prove [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) more generally for k'th powers. Similar methods work in any cyclic group.